# How to implement an OnChildClickListener?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I want to be able to click the menu item(font/textColor) in my ExpandableListView and then set the text on my second view to the appropriate format. How should I implement the listener? I am new to ExpandableListView and I don't know how to retrieve the information(I mean click) on each of the child item.

```
public class Second extends Activity {

ExpandableListView exv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    ExpandableListView exv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    exv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        //What should I put here?
            return false;
        }
    });


 }
 }
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
String [] parentList = {"Font", "Style", "Color"};
String [][] childList = {{"10", "20", "30"}, {"Red", "Black", "Blue"}};
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    tv.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    return tv;
}


public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return childList[groupPosition].length;
}


public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}


public int getGroupCount() {
    return parentList.length;
}


public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}


public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
    tv.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    return tv;
}


public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Implement [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) in your Custom Adapter(MyAdapter)'s getChildView

Answer (score 0):

test this code:

```
exv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        exv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```